# Do you really need force to accelerate or move things when there isnt any gravity and air resistance or any other force acting on the object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, free-body-diagram

Do you really need force to move things around you if there isn't any force acting on the object? For instance if I try to move a box around and there isn't gravity or any force acting on the box, do I really need force to move the box? Since there isn't anything resisting me, there isn't any normal force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the box starts at rest relative to you:**

By Newton's laws you need a net force to accelerate something that is at rest relative to you. It doesn't matter what other forces are present. You just need a net force.

If there are no forces acting on the object and then you push  it the object will accelerate and start moving relative to you (as long as no other force arise to counter your force, like for instance static friction).

However if there are no forces acting on an object that doesn't mean you can then get it to move from rest with no force. To change an object's velocity the object needs to experience a non-zero net force.

**If the box is already moving relative to you**

If the box is already moving then you don't need a net force to keep it moving. You would just need a net force to keep it accelerating. If there is no net force acting on the object after it starts moving, then you are right, you would not need a force to keep it moving. This is probably what you are getting at.

Comment: Thank you, i dont really understand, why do i need force to move things since there isnt anything resisting me, is there an equation to find out how much force i need to move the box when there isnt any other force resisting me, also if i try to jump when there isnt any force(gravity... etc) acting on me do i accelerate for example at (100000000000mph) since nothing resists me?

Comment: @Zheer $F=ma$. If you apply a force $F$ to an object of mass $m$, then it will have acceleration $a=F/m$ by Newton's second law. Any force causes an acceleration if that is the only force acting on it. A single force doesn't cause an infinite acceleration (unless that force is infinite).